# Split pdf file into multiple parts of specific file size

Tags: pdf, file-management, adobe-acrobat

We at the office have a very low attachment limit for the large PDF's we are required to send on a day-to-day basis. This mean's we have to manually split and send the PDF in multiple different files. For some people this causes confusion as they struggle to probably split the PDF, often confusing the order or splitting it page by page, etc.

Would it be possible to automatically split a PDF into multiple in an organized fashion? Say for example 1 page of a PDF is 1Mb and my split files must be 25Mb. If I take a 60 page PDF it should split into:

a PDF with pages 1-25 that's 25Mb

a PDF with pages 26-50 that's 25Mb

a PDF with pages 51-60 that's 10Mb

Obviously in more practical application the size of each page would vary but the idea remains the same. How could something like this be done? Everyone here are using standard Windows 7 64-bit workstations.

Comment: Have you try to use compression and split like zip?

Comment: I am interested less in ways to manually do it and more to automate the process, say if it was possible to have outlook quickly do it if the attached file is greater than the attachment limit or if there exists a small program to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the split by size task in [PDFsam Basic](http://www.pdfsam.org/download-pdfsam-basic/), it's free and open source, or the same feature online in [Sejda](https://www.sejda.com/split-pdf-by-size), in both you just put the max size (ex. 25MB) and they split *trying* to create files matching the required size. I say *trying* because PDF is a complex format with resources shared among pages so it's not always possible to exactly respect the requested size.

Note: I'm one of the authors

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use a compression tool such as WinRAR or 7Zip to put the pdf into a zip file then choose to split the archive into manageable sizes. once created you would end up with a multiple number of 10/25mb archive files that could be emailed then opened up like a single zip file at the other end to retrieve the complete .pdf

I noticed Romeo Ninov comment after writing my answer.